# Pentest methodology for industrial solutions PLC/DCS/Control Servers

Tags: penetration-test

which methodology of pentesting for industrial soltions (DCS/SCADA/PLC/Cotroler Servers network with OPC connectivity) would you recommend to apply?

Comment: A very careful one, preferably in a non-production environment. I've had industrial cameras go back on DHCP when I tried to port scan them. Allen Bradley PLCs will also fault out and require a hard reset if you show it something it doesn't expect, like a negative number in a timer register.

Comment: https://github.com/ITI/ICS-Security-Tools